# Remove text from label but keep text in span within it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove text from the label, but I want to keep the span text within it. Here is the part I want to remove: http://prntscr.com/kwblwc

```
<label for="wc_checkout_add_ons_2_yes" class="checkbox ">Yes (
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>
  4.95</span>)
</label>
```

So basically I want it just to stay €4.95

Comment: Don't put external links to code snippets, include it in your post.

Comment: i have put it in the code snippet, i have just added the screenshot if it is not clear to someone..

Comment: Yes. It comes from the plugin, in order to make the price work correctly. I have the answer. Thanks for you time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter your div by nodeType. This code should work.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.checkbox').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
  }).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="wc_checkout_add_ons_2_yes" class="checkbox ">Yes (
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>
  4.95</span>)
</label>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType

Comment: thank you so much ! that worked perfectly!